# Calling a specific constructor of a class from within another class

Tags: c++, object, constructor

In the project I'm working on, I have an outer class named "Camera", and inside this class I am tring to instantiate an object defined by a class named "Frame".  The Frame class has this in it's private section:

```
private:

// No default ctor
Frame();
// No copy ctor
Frame( Frame& );
// No assignment operator
Frame& operator=( const Frame& );
```

So I get an error when I try to instantiate a frame object since the default constructors are private.  In the public section of frame, however, there is this:

```
public:

Frame( char *pBuffer, int bufferSize );
```

So that is the constructor I need to call when instantiating Frame from within Camera.  Problem is I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.  I had the same issue with the Camera class (where the default constructors were in the private section), but all I had to do to fix that was:

```
Camera::Camera():mCamera(whatever params here){
    //constructor stuff here
}
```

in the implementation file.  When I try to do this same thing for Frame inside of the Camera class, however, I get tons of errors.

So how do I go about calling a particular constructor of an object from inside another object's class?

Comment: You need to use the member initializer list.

Comment: Please show an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: @AlokSave, There's something about the last code sample (and the text after) that suggests there's more to it.

Comment: What exactly is your sytax for 'do[ing] this same thing for Frame'? It should be `: mCamera(....), mFrame(....) {`

Comment: What do you mean by *When I try to do this same thing for Frame inside of the Camera class*? Please show the example code.

Comment: your question is unclear: the easy answer is that you do it exactly the same way you did for `mCamera`. but since you're asking, it's obvious that there's something trickier about `Frame`. so what is the tricky part? it seems to be missing in the question

Comment: @chris: There is not enough code to say anything at all than suggest proper use of member initializer list.

Comment: @AlokSave, That's true. That's why I wanted the sscce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am *guessing* that you tried using a `:` for every member in the [constructor initialization list](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) `Camera::Camera():mCamera():mFrame(NULL, 0)`. You need to separate the initializers with `,`, like so:

```
Camera::Camera() : mCamera() , mFrame(NULL, 0)
```

It may also be a good idea to read a [good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: This fixed the problem. I was trying to do everything in a seperate chunk of code, I didn't know it could be appended to the end of the constructor for the camera class.  Thanks!